# Customizing the frontpage of an Azure DevOps project

Tags: azure-devops

When you create a new Azure DevOps project it gives you a front page that looks like this.

[image]

Is there away to replace that "Welcome to the project" element with something else? I would like to add an readme instead where I can write various information to my team members.

I have been unable to locate settings that allows me to do that. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a repository and put a `README.md` on the root of the repository you will see it in the `Summary` page instead of "Welcome...".

[image]

You can also use Wiki page for this purpose.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or you can create a Wiki page and then set that Wiki page as the landing page for the Summary page.  But you MUST first create a git repository to get rid of the initial "Welcome to the project" message.  Then you will be presented with a new splash to "+Add Project Description".  Click on that button and then you can add a description and link to a ReadMe file that you described above OR link to a Wiki page that I described.

Comment: Hi @shayki,  would you know how to configure the languages that show up on the front page as well?  On my project it shows C++ and Python, although 100% of my code is Java...

Comment: @NicolasTherrien I have no idea :/ look like a bug, try to ask in: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/